# How Do I Cancel Out A CSS Property?

Tags: css

The page I am working on has many different CSS files attached to it, a boostrap.css, the master.css and a custom.css file.

I'm trying to remove a property, as I don't want there to be a a:hover property on the link in a menu. The master CSS file has

```
#topSurround a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

The bootstrap CSS file has

```
.nav > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

I don't want to edit these files, as they are core files with the template I am using and could be updated, so I am using a custom CSS file. Normally, I would set the property to default to override any previous uses of the property.

```
#topSurround a:hover {
    color: none; (doesn't work, as this isn't the correct default)
}
```

So, two questions: What is the default value for the color property (there doesn't seem to be one)? Is there an easier way to go about this without having to overwrite the core files?

Comment: First person to suggest using `!important` gets an automatic downvote ;)

Comment: @j08691 was thinking the same thing!

Comment: there's not a defualt specified color in W3C specs, you can temp remove _background-color: #eee;_ and check which color is assigned, and use it as "default" color.

Comment: Ok, I know and understand why !important is not good to use, but would it WORK in this situation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `color: inherit` to have the color use the value from its ancestors. [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) is odd in that it has different default values depending on context. A link, for example, will typically default to blue, while text will default to black.

If you need to override the existing style, **don't use a more specific selector**. Raising the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) means that you'll just have to use more selectors the next time you want to override it.

Instead, take advantage of the cascade by using a selector with identical specificity and make the override happen *after* the original style:

```
/* older style in some library */
.foo .bar .baz {
    color: blue;
}

...in an overriding CSS file...

.foo .bar .baz {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: I went with this... I added to my custom style sheet which overwrote the boostrap.css file that was causing the awkward hover background.     color: inherit; did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: LOL this is the first time in like 15 years that i've used inherit, and it worked beautifully.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

To cancel out the property you can use *`unset`* keyword.

So, in you custom css file you can do something like following:-

```
#topSurround a:hover {
    color: unset;
}
```

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) Web Docs:-

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent, and to its `initial value` if not. In other words, it behaves like the `inherit` keyword in the first case, and like the `initial` keyword in the second case. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all.

Comment: This is the correct answer regarding the question. Accepted answer is a best practice advice.

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to make a **more specific** CSS rule, such as:

```
body #topSurround a:hover {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Specificity is an important CSS concept, as described in this article:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Great answer! Also thank you for ***NOT*** using `!important` :-D

Comment: !important is as admission of failure, 99% of the time.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to have to say that this is *terrible* advice. It doesn't work well at all for larger projects. Don't ever raise specificity if you can avoid it. Match and take advantage of the cascade. Otherwise you'll end up playing specificity games and end up with styles where you've got 4 IDs, 3 classes and 2 element selectors.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend trying:

```
#topSurround a:hover {
  color: inherit;
}
```

As for how to overwrite what Bootstrap is adding, I think how you were doing it is best.

Answer (score 1):

Every CSS style has a natural default value. It's just not always `none`.

Some may be `0` (as in zero).

Some may be `auto`.

Sometimes `inherit` is the best option.

Colours can be set to `transparent`.

If you're unsure what the default is, try creating a dummy page with just a plain unstyled element, and use the browser dev tools to see what the styles are set to.